# How to make equal width or height constraints between widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In iOS's native AutoLayout constraints, It very easy to make a equal width constraints between ViewA and ViewB . And these two views will get a same width always.

But in flutter ,it seems can't be achived this kindof constraints so easily?

Do I have to make a SizedBox with specific width for both WidgetA and WidgetB explicitly?

Comment: It depends on the situation if your Widget A and B is on the same widget tree. Just create an parent wrapper widget that has width constraints and make both A and B widget a children.

Comment: Are you looking for properties like `mainAxisAlignment` or `crossAxisAlignment` on the ,`Row` and `Column` widgets? That's the closest to auto layout on Android and Constraint Layout chain in Android

Comment: @gtxtreme In fact , What I ask for is doing it in more general Container widget, not only in Row or Column

Comment: You can have a column inside a container if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put your widgets in a `Row()`, and wrap every widget in `Expanded()`. This way they will always have 50% width of the parent `Row()`. And if you need to constrain the width, just wrap the `Row()` in a `SizedBox()`.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 500.0,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: seems a solution for working ,but it may has some problem  when you met a situation like this ,there will be 4 widgets from left to right :WidgetA, WidgetB, WidgetC, WidgetD, And you want the WidgetA's width equal only to  WidgetC or WidgetD.And it seems can't be done by this method

Comment: In this case you can set `flex` property of `Expanded()` widget